# Yii2 - dynamically switch rules set in model

Tags: ajax, yii2, active-form

I want to dynamically substitute rules in model according to switch value on form.

In view:

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'validationUrl' => Url::toRoute('anounce/validation')
    ]);
?>
```

In controller:

```
public function actionValidation()
{
    $model = new Anounce();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->
        request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```

Excerpts from model:

```
class Anounce extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    private $currentRuleSet;    // Current validation set
    // Here are arrays of rules with assignment
    private $fullRuleSet;  // = [...];
    private $shortRuleSet; // = [...];
    private $minRuleSet;   // = [...];

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        $this->currentRuleSet = $this->fullRuleSet;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return $this->currentRuleSet;
    }

    public function beforeValidate()
    {
        if ($this->idanounce_type === self::FULL) {
            $this->currentRuleSet = $this->fullRuleSet;
        } else if ($this->idanounce_type === self::SHORTER) {
            $this->currentRuleSet = $this->shortRuleSet;
        } else if ($this->idanounce_type === self::MINIMAL) {
            $this->currentRuleSet = $this->minRuleSet;
        }
        return parent::beforeValidate();
    }
}
```

Variable `idanounce_type` is a switch between rules.
Unfortunately, validation made according to full rules set (or rules set used in `init`), despite on which `*RuleSet` value assigned to `currentRuleSet`.

How to write dynamic switching of rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want here is to change validation according to the user's input. You can do this by defining scenarios in your model.

So firstly set scenarios where you put in it the fields that are to be validated. Example if you have `username`, `password`, and `email` fields, and you defined two scenarios, in `SCENARIO_FIRST` only `username` and `password` will get validated.

```
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_FIRST => ['username', 'password'],
        self::SCENARIO_SECOND => ['username', 'email', 'password'],
    ];
}
```

Then in your controller, set the scenario according to the input:

```
public function actionValidation()
{
    $model = new Anounce();

    //example
    if($condition == true) 
    {
       $model->scenario = Anounce::SCENARIO_FIRST;
    }

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->
        request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```

Read more about scenarios here and how to use them with validation here:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios

Comment: Sounds good. Do you know how to change (!) rule according to scenario? In scenario ‘PUBLICATION’ I want to load publication image as `[['upload'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg’]` and for ‘PDF’ it should be `[['upload'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'pdf']`

Comment: You can have two rules, and use ON. As follows, [['upload'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg’, 'on'=>'PUBLICATION' ]
and then for the other rule 
[['upload'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'pdf', 'on'=>'PDF']

Comment: Great! And finally - switching of rules required not only when user change something, but also when data loaded to model from database (to set initial = default scenario). Unfortunately, I didn’t find method / event for this - when data just loaded from database into model. Maybe you know such method / event?

Comment: Why do you want to validate when the data is loaded from the database? Validation is done to check the user input :)

Comment: look at the sample rule before - I want to load file with the specific extension depends on selector pressed by user. So, I want to tell to `fileInput` to filter some extensions BEFORE validation. Doing it at validation of user input - too late

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want honestly. Clarify pls :)
Even if there is a default scenario, then this scenario will take effect when you're validating the data. I mean, the first step is the user inputs some values, then when he presses Post or Send or whatever, then I should be returning errors. The only to receive errors before this stage, is through javascript or HTML

Comment: Ok. Trying to imagine below what I want to tell:

I. User inputs something into text field. Yii2 application should validate - whether user input valid or not. 1. Predefined scenario; 2. User input; 3. Validation.

II. User inputs something to change scenario. Yii2 application change valid file extensions for `fileInput` according to changed scenario. Then user selects file according to `fileInput` settings. 1. User input; 2. Change scenario; 3. User input; 4. Validation.

Comment: Ok, so now I understand what you want, you want realtime validation. This is only possible through Frontend, through Javascript. Because since Yii2 is a serverside framework, it only works when the user input is submitted. Javascript is not my area of expertise though, I don't think I'll be able to help wih this :(

Comment: If you want a quick solution, that wont be very elegant though, you can cause the form to be submitted everytime the user input changes. This is a very bad solution though, but its the only solution you'd have if you don't want to use Javascript